# Refactor Upload function from aws-sdk V2 to the @aws-sdk/s3client V3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to refactor the old code related to function upload in V2 of aws-sdk to the new version V3.
The problem is that the output of the function PutObjectCommand does not have an element called Key which I  need it:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/putobjectcommand.html

You will find next the old sdk-code which give as Output an objedt with format S3.ManagedUpload.SendData and  I can extract the variable Key (path of uploaded file) as it exist in this object

```
                .upload({
                    Bucket: process.env.s3BucketAWS,
                    Key: key,
                    ContentType: mimeType,
                    Body: streamData,
                })
                .promise();
```

This is the new refactored code and it s working but I didnt found a way to extraxt the vaiable Key as there are 2 different key in the PutObjectCommandOutPut object and non of them used for path and also there is no other variable called path in that object

```
            const params = {
                Bucket: process.env.s3BucketAWS,
                Key: key,
                ContentType: mimeType,
                Body: streamData,
            };
            const command = new PutObjectCommand(params);
            data= await s3Client.send(command);
            return data
```

Comment: You are telling S3 what the key will be when you call the `PutObject` API, why do you need it in the response?

Comment: That's how the refactoring was suggested and this is the result of my research,  I could be wrong and you can provide a better solution